# If $a=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ and $b=\cos\theta-\sin\theta$, express $\sum_k\sin^k\theta(\sin^k\theta-\cos^k\theta)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> If $a=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ and $b=\cos\theta-\sin\theta$, then express
>   $$\sin \theta(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)+\sin^2\theta(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)+\sin^3\theta(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta) +\cdots$$
>   in terms of $a$ and $b$.

My observation :

$\underbrace{\sin \theta(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)}_1 +$$\underbrace{\sin^2\theta(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)}_2 +\underbrace{\sin^3\theta(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta)}_3 +\cdots\\$

$i.)$$\;\sin \theta(\sin \theta-\cos \theta) =\sin \theta (-b) =\bbox[4px, yellow] {-b\sin \theta} $ $\\$

$ii.) \;\sin^2 \theta(\sin^2 \theta-\cos^2 \theta)=\sin^2 \theta(\sin\theta-\cos
 \theta)(\sin \theta + \cos\theta)=\bbox[yellow, 4px]{-ab\sin^2\theta}
\\$

$\mathrm {Now} \\$

$iii.)$ $\sin^3\theta(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta)=\sin^3\theta (\sin\theta-\cos\theta)(\sin^2\theta +\sin\theta \cos\theta+\cos^2\theta) \\$

$=\sin^3\theta(-b)\left(1+\boxed {\sin\theta\cos\theta} \rightarrow\left\{\frac{a^2-b^2} {4} \right\} \right) \\$

$=\underline{\bbox[yellow, 4px] {-b\sin^3\theta\left(1+\frac{a^2-b^2}{4}\right)}}$

Can anyone suggest a way out?

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting b from a we have $a-b=\sin(x)+\cos(x)-(\cos(x)-\sin(x))$ thus $\frac{a-b}{2}=\sin(x)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin \theta(\sin \theta-\cos \theta)+\sin^2\theta(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)+\sin^3\theta(\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta) +\cdots$$

$$=-(\sin^2\theta)^0+\sum_{r=0}^\infty(\sin^2\theta)^r-\left((\sin\theta\cos\theta)^0+\sum_{r=0}^\infty(\sin\theta\cos\theta)^r\right)$$

$$=\dfrac1{1-\sin^2\theta}-\dfrac1{1-\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$

assuming $\sin^2\theta\ne1$ and $\sin\theta\cos\theta=\dfrac{\sin2\theta}2$ whose absolute value  $\le\dfrac12$

Solve the two simultaneous equations to find $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$